# Upgrading Sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text

I want to upgrade Sublime Tex 3, downloaded the deb, but I get the following error:

```
Breaks existing package 'sublime-text-installer' conflict: sublime-text ()
```

How do I upgrade Sublime correctly?

Comment: try to unistall the current sublime text and install the new version again, there is a big chance to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have sublime package so this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade sublime-text
```

Comment: This assumes that `sublime-text` is in one of OP's systems package repositories, which is not the default.

Answer (score 7):

Happened to me too. A quick search on the internet revealed that you can solve this by removing the deb package information using the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo dpkg -r sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
```

run this before installing new package..!